# Structuring ASMX Web Service

Tags: web-services

I am developing an `Cloud Media` application. There will be an android app that will use the cloud to upload/download photos, audio and videos.

So, There will be an Web Servicethat will have all Web Methods.

> 1. Photo (GetAll, GetByTag, GetByAlbum, GetFavorites)
> 2. Audio (~Same)
> 3. Video (~Same) Also Auth functions + Other functions

So, my point is, there will be 1 ASMX with all these functions.

It would be better to seperate functions like this:

> Photosasmx (Contains only 4-5 functions which return photos)
>
> Audioasmx(same)
>
> Videoasmx (same)
>
> Authasmx (web methods only for auth)

What is better?